# Cross compile libcurl for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Tags: c++, linux, curl

I have been trying to cross compile libcurl 7.35.0 from ubuntu eclipse for  arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc++. 
I have included -lcurl optons in GCC++ linker. when I am trying to compile the code in G++ compiler for the below code everything is going well and no error was there after building.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     return
}
```

But when I am trying to cross compile using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc++ but trying to Build this produces compilation errors:

/usr/include/curl/curlrules.h:143:41: error: size of array ‘**curl_rule_01**’ is negative
/usr/include/curl/curlrules.h:153:53: error: size of array ‘**curl_rule_02**’ is negative

Kindly help me to guide how to cross compile libcurl for ARM.

Answer (score 5):

I remember back when I had to cross-compile curl... what a day! What curl is doing is fairly odd, but yet clever.

if you look at that line you see this:

```
typedef char
  __curl_rule_01__
    [CurlchkszEQ(long, CURL_SIZEOF_LONG)];
```

and if you look at CurlchkszEQ, you get

```
#define CurlchkszEQ(t, s) sizeof(t) == s ? 1 : -1
```

So this routine is enforcing that `sizeof(long) == CURL_SIZEOF_LONG`, if it does not, it will put a negative number in that array initializer and cause the build to fail.

Here's the deal, `CURL_SIZEOF_LONG` is defined in `curlbuild.h`, and it is defined to `8`... on an x86_64 machine. That is, in `/usr/include/curl/curlbuild.h` it is set to `8`. You don't care about x86_64 though! You're compiling for arm... a 32-bit architecture where `sizeof(long) == 4`, not `8` and `CURL_SIZEOF_LONG` is improperly set to `8`! So it appears your compiler is picking up on the system wide, x86_64 curl header files at `/usr/include/...` rather than the headers for the cross compiler! (for example mine are in `/opt/cross/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/include/...`, but yours probably are not).

So when compiling the compiler resovles that `sizeof(long) == 4 != CURL_SIZEOF_LONG` and properly crashes. The way to fix the problem is simple in theory, just change your configuration in your compiler to use the cross-compiler includes. In Eclipse, I am not sure how to do it, though I am sure it is possible.

You might find it easier just to build curl from the terminal like so:

```
curl $ ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/path/to/your/arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi
... configure stuff ...
curl $ make && make install
```

Comment: @JJoshua Rahm Thank you for your comments. I did try to fix the problem manually changing definitions in curlbuild.h like this:
CURL_SIZEOF_LONG 4
CURL_SIZEOF_CURL_OFF_T 4
but then I get the error 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: file not recognized: File format not recognised and Collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.

Comment: Right, your cross compiler does not have the correct path set. It is finding the x86 headers, and the x86 libraries. When you try to link, your cross compiler is trying to link the arm binaries with the x86 libraries. In eclipse you need to tell it to look for the arm libraries and arm headers. I.e your build settings are using `-I/usr/include -L/usr/include` They should use something like `-I/usr/share/cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/include -L/usr/share/cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib` (The exact path depends on how the cross compiler was built)

Comment: @JJoshua Rahm I am very new in this section.Could you please guide me how to set the proper path and what command should I set. Actually when I am running simple code eclipse and cross compile with arm-linux-gnuebi compiler it is working perfectly as I have set the build settings in GCC C++ compiler with " -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0"  and GCC C++ linker path is "-L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib -lcurl -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro". This problem happens only when I am trying to compile   curl libery with arm-linux-gnueabi.

Comment: Cross compiling is hard partly because the compilers are very sensitive to the environment in which they were built. I don't know how you obtained your compiler, but here's what I can generally say about cross-compiling:

Comment: sorry- accidentally hit <enter>

By default, you cross compiler should use the proper paths. Like gcc, it will automagically point to the proper `include` and `lib` directories for that architecture. It might help if I knew exactly how your Eclipse was set up to compile this app. If I had to guess, it is probably explicitly setting the library path with `-L/usr/lib` which is _bad_ because that is where the x86 libraries are. You'll want to remove that. Have you tried compiling your app on the command line? The simple example you provided above should compile easily.

Comment: Where do you get the `--host=` parameter value from?