# Building Cross-Compiler: Intel Xeon E5649 >>> ARMv7 with libcURL

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, libcurl

i don't exactly understand the manual/help from libcURL. I'm trying to build a Cross-Compiler including the libcURL library. I installed a Cross-Compiler on my Server with the help of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9yFyWsyyGk&feature=iv&src_vid=hzZHcH5quow&annotation_id=annotation_3508860269) and can start it with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc hello_simple.c`. I could compile simple c-code like `printf ("Hello World");` After that i tried to install libcURL and read that I need to compile the lib and use the `configure` file to set the build and host. I used different configuration like: `sudo ./configure --build=i586-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux --target=arm-linux --prefix=/home/nevadmin/dev/gcc` but neither did one worked. I think I'm making somewhere mistakes. This is the output after configuration is made:

```
curl version:     7.46.0
Host setup:       arm-unknown-linux-gnu
Install prefix:   /home/nevadmin/dev/gcc
Compiler:         gcc
SSL support:      no      (--with-{ssl,gnutls,nss,polarssl,mbedtls,cyassl,axtls,winssl,darwinssl} )
SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
zlib support:     no      (--with-zlib)
GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
TLS-SRP support:  no      (--enable-tls-srp)
resolver:         default (--enable-ares / --enable-threaded-resolver)
IPv6 support:     no      (--enable-ipv6)
Unix sockets support: enabled
IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn,winidn})
Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
Built-in manual:  enabled
--libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
ca cert bundle:   no
ca cert path:     no
LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
RTSP support:     enabled
RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
PSL support:      no      (libpsl not found)
HTTP2 support:    disabled (--with-nghttp2)
Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP GOPHER HTTP IMAP POP3 RTSP SMTP TELNET TFTP
```

My Server cpuinfo:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 44
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5649  @ 2.53GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x15
cpu MHz         : 2533.423
cache size      : 12288 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes hypervisor lahf_lm ida arat dtherm
bogomips        : 5066.84
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

And my controller:

```
Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 298.80
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x3
CPU part        : 0xc08
CPU revision    : 2
```

Using for example `gcc hello_world.c -o hello_world` it compile it for the amd processor architecture and not arm. It seems I'm missing the linking to the library for libcURL? I appreciate every help. And sorry my english, it's not my native language.

Linking with `L/home/nevadmin/dev/gcc -lcurl` is working an I can compile a c-code with libcURL but it still compiling it for amd64 and not arm. :/

Comment: FYI: have already looked at [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/)? It already provides *libcurl* recipe and it will handle most of the cross-compilation tasks for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the proper compiler to use when you configure curl. If you look at curl's configure output from

```
./configure --help
```

You'll see this at the end:

```
...
Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor

Use these variables to override the choices made by `configure' or to help
it to find libraries and programs with nonstandard names/locations.
```

You can set these variables with a command line like:

```
CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc ./configure --build=i586-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux --target=arm-linux --prefix=/home/nevadmin/dev/gcc
```

(You don't need the "sudo" to configure.)

**gcc** by itself will give you an AMD executable. You need to use **arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc** to get an ARM executable.

Notice that in your curl configuration output it says

```
Compiler:         gcc
```

That's why your getting a curl library built for your AMD. Bibliothek is called "library" in English. ;-)

If you continue to have problems cross compiling for ARM you could take a look at the binary releases of the cross compilation tool chain [ELLCC](http://ellcc.org). As of version 0.1.21 it comes with several pre-compiled libraries, including curl. Here's the [ChangeLog](http://ellcc.org/releases/ChangeLog).

Comment: Pennigton. Thank you, I could change the Compiler in `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` but now the is that I get a negative vlaue with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.: `/usr/include/curl/curlrules.h:142:3: error: size of array ‘curl_rule_01’ is negative curl_rule_01 ^ /usr/include/curl/curlrules.h:152:3: error: size of array ‘curl_rule_02’ is negative curl_rule_02 ^`
The `gcc` Compiler can compile it without any errors. I just need to link the library `-L/home/nevadmin/dev/gcc -lcurl` but `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` brings the same error with and without the linking to the library.

Comment: @Steinfeld: It looks like You're using your x86 curl include files rather than the files in the curl sources your trying to build for ARM. Specifically, curlbuild.h is generated by configure. That's why you're getting this error.

Comment: yeah I found only 1 post about this. Here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732753/cross-compile-libcurl-for-arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc) it's written the same. But I tried the solution and it didn't worked for me. Man I think I will never make a cross compiler after this ^^